# copying and placing elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I replace the id of player with the href of the listen_button? I'm sure it's crazy easy so please don't laugh, I'm new to jquery! Also there will be multiples of these sets on the page.

```
<ul class="controls">
<li id="download" class="download_button"><span>&nbsp;</span><a  
href="media/audio.mp3">Download</a></li>
<li id="listen" class="listen_button"><span>&nbsp;</span><a class="play"   
href="media/audio.mp3">Listen</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="player" id="play"><audio controls="controls"></audio></div>
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Why would you want to change the id of the player to the href of the listen_button?

Comment: *Why* do you want to replace the id? Perhaps your problem can be solved in a better way?

Comment: If there's multiple sets you don't want to use ids. They're unique identifiers across the entire document.

Comment: Here is more code. 
jsfiddle.net/rbJgy/1

Answer (score 0):

In simplest form, just get the href attribute from the play button and set it to the id attribute of the player.

```
$("#play").attr("id") = $(".play").attr("href");
```

However, I agree with Jon and Sjoerd. This doesn't make much sense. What are you trying to accomplish actually? There might be a better solution.

**UPDATE**

Code above doesn't work, try this instead (value should be second parameter):

```
$("#play").attr("id", $(".play").attr("href"));
```

Comment: I'm using MediaElement.js as my audio player. I am also using a script to hide the player until the user clicks on the listen button. Once that happens the listen "href" is sent to the player's "src"
`player.attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));`
The script needs to attach the listen button to the player. It does this by using this code, I think. 
`player_div = $(this).attr('rel');`
I could change out 'rel' for anything. I was thinking the href would be best but as long as they connect I'm good to go. 
It could work if we take the #play "rel" and replace it with the .play "id"

Comment: Also how and where do I add this code? Sorry for all the simple questions. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I'd have to see more of your code to really work out a solution. However, take a look at this fiddle, it might help: http://jsfiddle.net/4rwmP/2/

Comment: I modified it a little
`$(".play").attr("rel", $(".player").attr("id"));`
It works but it seems to not be doing this function for each set, it does it for the whole site. How can I get this to repeat this function for every instance of this set? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#play').attr('id', $('.play').attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why you want to do this:

```
$(".player").attr("id", $("a .play").attr("href"));
```

Comment: I modified it a bit, it works but where do I put this and how can I make it do this for multiple sets?